# What should i Use instead of document.getElementById for this to work

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Hello I have a problem with my javascript. Somebody already informed me to not use document.getElementById in my code but what should i use instead so it works and should i change something else too in my code?

I'm making a website where users can upload posts to the website.

```
            echo '<a class="annons-tb">
              <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>
              <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
              <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                <input type="button" class="button1" name="id" value="Visa Mer Info" onclick="on()"></a>
              <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
              <div id="text">
              <img src="data:img/gallery/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row["imgFullNameGallery"]).'" width="250" height="250">
              <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
              <p1>Beskrivning: '.$row["descGallery"].'</p1>
              <div id=p-delen">
              <br />
              <p>Pris: '.$row["prisGallery"].'</p>
              <p>Namn: '.$row["namnGallery"].'</p>
              <p>Mail: '.$row["emailGallery"].'</p>
              <p>TelefonNummer: '.$row["nummerGallery"].'</p>
              </div>
              </div></div><script>
                function on() {
                  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
                }

                function off() {
                  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
                }
                </script>';

        }
    }
    ?>
      </div>
```

I have already made an overlay effect so when you click on a button you can view more info about the post, but now when you press the button it always shows the extra info for the first post.

Comment: the code above - does this get rendered in a loop of some sort? I presume, judging by `$row["prisGallery"]` that it does and is the result from a db query?! To use `document.getElementById` you need to know the ID and the ID MUST be unique - you would be better using, perhaps, `document.querySelectorAll` with a valid identifying class / attribute selector. Also - you would not define functions in a loop either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assigned an event listener to both types of elements ( `input[type='button']` and `div` ) but remove the ID attribute- replace with a class of the same value for example then you can easily monitor for events being triggered upon any/all like this.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
        Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'div.overlay, button.button1' ) ).forEach( function(node){
            node.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                switch( this.tagName ){
                    case 'INPUT':
                        this.style.display='block';
                    break;
                    case 'DIV':
                        this.style.display='none';
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above uses the `forEach` method to iterate through the collection of nodes found using `document.querySelectorAll` - however some browsers do not support this method being used on a `nodelist` hence using the `Array.prototype.slice.call` to convert the nodelist to an array.

The supporting HTML/PHP ( essentially the same but ID attributes have been changed for classes and it has been indented properly )

```
    echo '
        <a class="annons-tb">
            <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>
            <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
            <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
            <input type="button" class="button1" name="id" value="Visa Mer Info">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">
                <img src="data:img/gallery/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row["imgFullNameGallery"]).'" width="250" height="250" />
                <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                <p1>Beskrivning: '.$row["descGallery"].'</p1>
                <div class="p-delen">
                    <br />
                    <p>Pris: '.$row["prisGallery"].'</p>
                    <p>Namn: '.$row["namnGallery"].'</p>
                    <p>Mail: '.$row["emailGallery"].'</p>
                    <p>TelefonNummer: '.$row["nummerGallery"].'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
}
?>
  </div>
```

I made a couple of corrections to the above ( which was not tested when written - sorry ) and have put together a demo. You'll notice that the javascript appears before the HTML body - the event listeners get registed because of the event listener already assigned to the body which essentially waits for all the DOM elements to be rendered before trying to bind to specific elements. In essence you can do like this or after the repeated content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Alternative for document.getElementById</title>
        <script>
            /*
                I had made a slight error with the selector - it should be input.button1
                rather than button.button1

                The action invoked by the button also needed to be changed - it now
                navigates up the DOM tree to it's parent then to the parent's sibling
            */
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'div.overlay, input.button1' ) ).forEach( function(node){
                    node.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        switch( this.tagName ){
                            case 'INPUT':
                                this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display='block';
                            break;
                            case 'DIV':
                                this.style.display='none';
                            break;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            html *{box-sizing:border-box;}
            #wrapper{width:100%;height:100vh;margin:0;padding:0;}
            #wrapper > a.annons-tb{ padding:1rem;height:5rem;width:100%;display:inline-block; }
            #wrapper > div.overlay{ background:whitesmoke;border:1px dotted rgba(100,100,100,0.25);padding:1rem;margin:1rem auto;display:none }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>
        <?php
            /*
                To emulate the db call
                a static array can be used
            */
            $rs=array(
                array(
                    'titleGallery'=>'Mega Gallery 1',
                    'descGallery'=>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci ipsum, commodo pulvinar rutrum non, congue ut justo. Phasellus nec scelerisque diam, ut cursus felis.',
                    'imgFullNameGallery'=>'Gallery 1',
                    'prisGallery'=>'abc',
                    'namnGallery'=>'bob',
                    'emailGallery'=>'gal1@example.com',
                    'nummerGallery'=>'0141 353 3780'
                ),
                array(
                    'titleGallery'=>'Super Gallery 2',
                    'descGallery'=>'urabitur tristique libero non lorem blandit eleifend. Sed gravida ut purus vitae dignissim. Aenean pellentesque, diam ac euismod eleifend, lorem mauris dapibus lorem, id fermentum augue nisi at nisl.',
                    'imgFullNameGallery'=>'Gallery 2',
                    'prisGallery'=>'def',
                    'namnGallery'=>'rita',
                    'emailGallery'=>'gal2@example.com',
                    'nummerGallery'=>'0131 551 7488'
                ),
                array(
                    'titleGallery'=>'Awesome Gallery 3',
                    'descGallery'=>'Morbi ultrices nisl elementum augue sagittis porttitor. Nulla posuere molestie quam posuere tempus. Sed convallis metus mi, quis faucibus est lobortis sed.',
                    'imgFullNameGallery'=>'Gallery 3',
                    'prisGallery'=>'ghi',
                    'namnGallery'=>'sue',
                    'emailGallery'=>'gal3@example.com',
                    'nummerGallery'=>'01307 462 059'
                )
            );
            /*
                for the static array a foreach rather than while loop
                but essentially the same...

                I prefer use printf to constantly escaping out from the html to
                include the variable but again essentially the same as the original
                except for the lack of ID attributes
            */
            foreach( $rs as $row ){
                printf('
                    <a class="annons-tb">
                        <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/%s);"></div>
                        <h3>%s</h3>
                        <p>%s</p>
                        <input type="button" class="button1" name="id" value="Visa Mer Info">
                    </a>
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text">
                            <img src="data:img/gallery/jpeg;base64,%s" width="250" height="250" />
                            <h3>%s</h3>
                            <p1>Beskrivning: %s</p1>
                            <div class="p-delen">
                                <br />
                                <p>Pris: %s</p>
                                <p>Namn: %s</p>
                                <p>Mail: %s</p>
                                <p>TelefonNummer: %s</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>',

                    $row['imgFullNameGallery'],
                    $row['titleGallery'],
                    $row['descGallery'],
                    $row['imgFullNameGallery'],
                    $row['titleGallery'],
                    $row['descGallery'],
                    $row['prisGallery'],
                    $row['namnGallery'],
                    $row['emailGallery'],
                    $row['nummerGallery']
                );
            }

        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```